# how to style a tel link with different colors on different pages css

Tags: html, css, tel

I currently have a tel link on my site:

HTML

```
Give us a call today on <a href="tel:+441234123456">01234123456</a>
```

CSS

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
  font-size:12px;
  font-color:white;
}
```

The only problem is that on another page I have the telephone number showing as part of some text and I need to show the tel number on this page in black and I am not sure how I override this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there difference about structure/ids or class names in this other peticular page ? If yes, then create from those difference a specific selector. Another way is to add a class on body via javascript on that page (checking uri) and use a selector with that class to overide the color rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: add an specific class to this phone container.

```
<a class="phone-green" href="tel:+441234123456">01234123456</a>
```

Then add a class modifier in css file:

```
a[href^="tel:"].phone-green {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `color:` attribute instead of `font-color:`.

I would go like this :

```
a {
  font-size:12px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

You should give a class to your `a` tag, like this :

```
<a class="phone-number">+4412666666</a>
```

in order to assign a color to this specific class, like this :

```
a.phone-number {
  font-size:12px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: hi gangai, I have that already, but need to show it as black on another page